# Array element in LINQ where clause causes run time error vs compile time error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've learned you can't use an array element in a where clause with LINQ. For example:

```
Department department = db.Departments.Single(d => d.DepartmentID == teams[i].DepartmentID);
```

That fails. However, I am curious as to why this isn't caught at compile time? Is there a case where this could work which would prevent a blanket compile time error for this kind of statement?

Comment: Yes, LINQ to Objects (for example)
. In that it would work perfectly fine.

Comment: Not necessarily related but would moving `teams[i].DepartmentID` into a variable before hand resolve this error? e.g. `var departmentId = teams[i].DepartmentID` and then referencing `departmentId` instead?

Comment: Yes, that works. But it gets verbose quickly if you're selecting on various arrays.

Answer (score 5):

It's not caught at compile-time because it's entirely valid C#. The expression is converted to an appropriate expression tree - it's just an expression tree which isn't supported by the Entity Framework. A different LINQ provider might be able to support it.

The C# compiler doesn't know anything about LINQ providers, and shouldn't. The only relevant aspects it knows about are how to construct expression trees from lambda expressions, how to call extension methods, and how to use query expressions (not used here, but normally part of LINQ).

It's very important to distinguish between *language* support and *library* support - particularly in the case of LINQ.

Comment: Hm, haven't you heard about some post-compile checkers for IQueryable providers? I think that can be nice feature. Or everyone thinks that writing unit-tests is enough?

Comment: @nsinreal: If it's a "post-compile checker" then it's not at compile-time, is it? It's post-compile-time, by definition. Yes, such a thing could potentially be useful - but I'd personally look at integration tests first.

Answer (score 2):

The c# compiler turns that code into a valid expression tree, and the LinqToEntities query translator doesn't get a chance to work with that tree until runtime.

The c# compiler can't know the capabilities of the LinqToEntities query translator.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of compilation C# compiler just tries to make your code as a valid expression tree and if your code can be converted into a valid expression tree it will never give a compile time error. In compile time it will never checks if the data is coming or not, if the index is in range or not. But at the run-time only when your code tries to load data into it then only code gives the exception.
Since your code is correct and an expression tree can be formed so its not giving any error but at run-time when its trying to look data into it it is throwing an exception. As far as I know you might be getting index out of range exception. Since you have used "teams[i].DepartmentID", if the ith value of team does not contains any department then it will give you this error. If you are using a loop then iterate the loop till i-1.